# How to replace a string in jq? I tried the function sub and it fails

Tags: jq

I am using jq compiled from sources, and I do this

```
jq -r '.transaction_details[]|[.payer_info.payer_name.alternate_full_name]' transactions.txt | grep -i godaddy
"GoDaddy.com, LLC"
```

The issue is that I need to replace the "," inside Godaddy, and it fails:

```
jq -r '.transaction_details[]|[.payer_info.payer_name.alternate_full_name|=sub(",";"-")]' transactions.tx
```

How do I replace a string with another inside a single member?
I also tried with

```
jq -r "walk(if type == "string" then gsub(","; "-") else . end)"
```

and it fails.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Please also see [mcve]

Comment: Can you check my answer is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the paucity of details in the question, perhaps the only thing that can be said with any degree of confidence is that the query using `walk` should, in a bash or bash-like environment, be:

```
jq -r 'walk(if type == "string" then gsub(","; "-") else . end)'
```

In a Windows environment, there is much to be said for using jq’s -f command-line option.

Answer (score -1):

You need add some parenthesis :

```
jq -r '.transaction_details[]|
      [ .payer_info.payer_name.alternate_full_name | (.|=sub(",";"-") )
      ] '
```